# Search function made with PHP against SQL not working as intended

Tags: php, sql, database, search

I'm working on a way for users to search for a movie within my database. When I add the option for limiting the searches by a year, the searches still get returned as like the year filtering never was added to the query. When I run this query directly in Mysql, it works like it should but not when I'm using PHP. What am I doing wrong here?

```
include 'connectdatabase.php';      


$searchyear=2018;   
$searchtitles = getpostAJAX("searchtitle"); 
mysql_set_charset('utf8');

$temps = explode("*", $searchtitles);

mysql_set_charset('utf8');
$querystring="SELECT title from Movie where title LIKE '%".$temps[0]."%'";
$arr_lengths = count($temps);
for($is=0;$is<$arr_lengths;$is++)
    {
        $querystring.= " or title LIKE '%".$temps[$is]."%'";
    }

$querystring.= " and YEAR(release_date) = '".$searchyear."'";
$querystring.= ";";

$innerresult = mysql_query($querystring);
if (!$innerresult) err("Login Query Error: ".mysql_error());

while ($innerrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($innerresult)) {                   
    $output.="    title='".$innerrow['title']."'\n";
}
```

(there is a Movie in my database with the name "Zootopia" that releases 2016 but it gets returned from this query anyways.)

Comment: `$innerresult = mysql_query($querystring)`

Comment: @Farkie I think it's a typo. OP have results

Comment: oh yea, thanks :P forgot it when copying and pasting

Comment: Your query works as expected for me. Try to search for Zootopia omitting year: maybe you have a duplicate.

Comment: hmm, maybe it works in this smaller version of it... I'll tast it once more and use the whole code if it's working

Comment: Hey fusion3k, I edited the code to use the original code that I am using in my application,  maybe it's the for loop that's causing it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap `OR` conditions by brackets:

```
#                                           ↓
$querystring="SELECT title from Movie where (title LIKE '%".$temps[0]."%'";

(...)

$querystring.= ") and YEAR(release_date) = '".$searchyear."'";
#               ↑
```

Otherwise, `AND` condition is evaluated only for last title.

Comment: ah, works! Thanks a ton fusion3k